# Counting the number of subsets with at least one specific element.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $X = \left\{x_1, \dots , x_n \right\}$. I'd like to count the number of subsets of $X$ that have at least one of $k$ elements from $X$.

For example, how many subsets of $X$ contain $x_1$, or $x_2$, or both.

Comment: The number of subsets containing neither $x_1$ nor $x_2$ is $2^{n-2}$.

Comment: You seem to state three entirely different problems here: (1) number of subsets with at least $k$ elements; (2) number of subsets with at least one member of a specified subset; (3) number of subsets with every member of a specified subset.

Comment: @almagest Yea, I see what you're saying.  Please see my edit.

Comment: @DemetriP Much better! So now use lulu's hint (which works in the general case as well as $k=2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be an $n$-element set and let $Y$ be a $k$-subset of $X$.  Suppose you want to find the number of subsets of $X$ that contain at least one element from $Y$. This value is equal to the total number of subsets of $X$ minus the number of subsets of $X$ that contain no elements from $Y$.  This difference is equal to $2^n - 2^{n-k}$.